# UIButton not working on a subview of UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to create a custom one-button AlertViewController in Swift, I use window.addSubview() to show the AlertView, but when touch the button on the AlertView, the func buttonTapped() is not working, below is my code, please tell me what's wrong here, thanks.

MyAlertViewController.swift

```
class MyAlertViewController: UIViewController {
    var button: UIButton!
    var contentView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUp()
    }

    func setUp(){
        contentView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,300))
        contentView.center = view.center
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        button = UIButton(type: .System)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(50, 150, 100, 40)
        button.setTitle("button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(button)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
        view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject?){
        print("button tapped")
    }

    func show(){
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow! as UIWindow
        view.frame = window.bounds
        window.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

ParentViewController.swift (is the rootViewController of my window)

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        button = UIButton(type: .System)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(110,269,100,30)
        button.setTitle("show", forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject?){
        MyAlertViewController().show()
    }

}
```

[image]

I found out if I change ParentViewController.swift as below, the button on the alert view can work correctly.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    var button: UIButton!
    var vc: MyAlertViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
        button = UIButton(type: .System)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(110,269,100,30)
        button.setTitle("show", forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject?){
        vc = MyAlertViewController()
        vc.show()
    }

}
```

But I intended to show this alert view each time the user get new messages,so it would show up at any time and on any ViewController , so I don't want to declare it in each ViewController, so How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TLDR**;

You have to **retain** an instance of MyAlertViewController().

Change to this and it will work (as you've already done):

```
// keep some reference
var alert: MyAlertViewController?

func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject?){
    alert = MyAlertViewController()
    alert?.show()
}
```

---

**More explanation**

The `button.addTarget(self, ...)` that is called inside MyAlertViewController **does not retain `self`.**

The last line of the doc of `addTarget` function said that:

> // ... the action cannot be NULL. Note that the target is not retained.*

So there will be no `self` to send action to after leaving of this function:

```
func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject?){
    MyAlertViewController().show()
}
```

---

**Another option**,
 is to keep `self` variable in MyAlertViewController:

```
// retain self manually
var mySelf: MyAlertViewController?

func setUp(){
    ...
    // reference to self
    mySelf = self
    button.addTarget(mySelf, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so MyAlertViewController().show() is not creating a strong reference to MyAlertViewController instance?

Comment: @Keater Yes. So the line button.addTarget... basically do nothing.

Comment: Very Thanks.. .

Comment: Thanks, it helped me in similar scenario